# How to create custom color names in matplotlib using hex values?

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization

So I have been trying to create a consistent colormap or color codes using hex values.
So let's say that I have a below data frame:

[image: DataFrame]

I would like to use the position from DEPT_NAME column as a color code, just like you can use 'k', 'blue', 'red', etc.

I was thinking about creating a pickle dictionary with positions and hex values, but I couldn't find any information in matplotlib documentation on how can I create a colormap for this specific situation.

It would be very helpful to use it when plotting other graphs that also take DEPT_NAME values as the color codes would be consistent across all the graphs.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to use the names from your dataframe as color specifications in matplotlib. This is in principle possible, although they need to be lower case.

So having a dataframe like

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors

colormap = pd.DataFrame({"name" : ["Analyst", "Local Hero"],
                         "color" : ["#396ab1", "#990011"]})
```

You can register your color names,

```
colormap["name"] = colormap["name"].apply(lambda x: x.lower())   
c = dict(zip(*colormap.values.T))
mcolors.get_named_colors_mapping().update(c)
```

and use them in matplotlib:

```
plt.plot([1,2], [1,1], color='analyst')
plt.plot([1,2], [1,2], color="local hero")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks! Would it also work if I use cmap=c instead of color='analyst'?
So that I could plot graph for multiple positions and the value for each position has a distinct color?

Comment: A colormap (`cmap`) is a mapping of numbers to color. So, `cmap=c` will not work. But I'm not certain I understand what you are trying to achieve with such command.

Comment: thanks for your answer. So basically I am plotting graphs that show different involvement from people who have certain positions. So for instance there would be a bar graph that shows what positions where involved in a certain project over time - so for each day there would be a stacked bar that shows number of hours they worked on the project. There may be different positions involved in different projects, but I would like to have the colormap to show all of these positions always in the same color. i.e. analyst - always green,etc. do you happen to know how to do it?

Comment: For a bar graph you would anyways need to set the colors themselves, via the `facecolors` argument.